# Questions related to shopify application testing and development

Tags: testing, shopify

1. I can not find *Publish Beta App* button at the partners dashboard, How to REAL test my application? I have tested with the private app API.
2. What will happen If a shop owner click the INSTALL button at app store after the app published? And how to get variables about the client?
   I tracked the installation of A app, got:

   http://app.com/shopify/?shop=schuppe-conn-and-oconner436.myshopify.com&t=ed8f063be7d4583fbd194836b12599b3&timestamp=1339572934&signature=e7451b42b2fd5f67465c0b98bcaf7668

   But some document says I will get something like:

   http://app.com/shopify?code=TEMP_TOKEN

   Which is correct?
3. About the PHP library: https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/ohShopify.php
   I can get a limited time permission to operate the shop, but how to get the permission later? (I can not get shop owner to click the INSTALL button again).

Comment: This Is three different questions and should be split up.

Answer (score 1):

When someone clicks the "install" button at the Shopify App store, they are redirected to your apps URL *(return URL if you are using OAuth)* with the `shop` parameter attached to the request.

Using your example, when I click "install" in the App store, I am redirected to `http://app.com/shopify/?shop=schuppe-conn-and-oconner436.myshopify.com`. In your app, all you have to do is check to see if that param is there, and respond accordingly.

In Ruby, this looks like:

```
if params[:shop].present?
  redirect_to "/auth/shopify?shop=#{params[:shop]}"
else
  # render the normal page
end
```

As for the PHP question:

> About the PHP library: https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/ohShopify.php I can get a limited time permission to operate the shop, but how to get the permission later? (I can not get shop owner to click the INSTALL button again).

I think that the thing you are missing is that when you get through the OAuth process, you should have a token that you need to save. This token, along with your app's shared secret, is needed to construct the URL you need to connect to the API. That is what ohShopify is doing for a session, but if you need to connect to the API without the merchant *(Shopify store owner)* logging in, then you need to store that OAuth token.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you split up your questions to one per thread. I’ll answer one here.

> About the PHP library: https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/ohShopify.php I
>   can get a limited time permission to operate the shop, but how to get
>   the permission later? (I can not get shop owner to click the INSTALL
>   button again).

Computed passwords to access a shop’s API do not expire or change until the app is uninstalled from that shop or until the app requests and receives differently scoped API access permissions.